# How to Handle SQLServer Archive

Tags: sql-server, bigdata

Hello i need help to handle BigData

I have a Production BDD that got a lot of information.
Around 50 table but some of them are requested really few time.
I have a table history that record every change in other table with:

- IdElement
- TypeElement
- ColumnChange
- OldValue
- NewValue
- Author

This table is BIG

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Changes;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Changes c
Left Join ChangeSets cs on cs.IdChangeSet = c.ChangesetID 
Where cs.Date > '2016-12-18';
```

Execute in 22 minute....
174 011 299 Rows 
 2 4048 318 Rows less than a month

And I don't need it a lot just some check sometime when I need to watch what the client did to cause a bug.

I would like to pass every data older than one month in a new database with the same History table that could be then requested when I need info.

Any way to do it automatically?

A best tool practise for this?

Is it necessary?(I don't have infrastructure for handle big data and my company don't want to upgrade a lot so I must find better way to make my SQL Server lighter)

It look like because in a test db after remove all older than 1 month the query where way faster on the db (about the history table of course).

I don't usually check what a client have done 5 month ago but need to keep it for legal and security reason

PS: I also restore a lot of db for test and debug. and it's longer if the db is bigger. So archive in another db would also help me to restore them faster for test purpose

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this of course by archiving it automatically every day when your database is not in production time (after working hours i presume).

you can check [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1121/archiving-data-in-sql-server/) for the above solution.

Alas, there is another manual way to do it.

1. Backup the original DB to another storage (in case you needed old data)
2. Delete all unneeded data from original DB, keep the needed data in production DB

To delete data in DB, please follow [these tips.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4109/best-practices-for-deleting-sql-server-data/)

Goodluck!